# How do I get a file's age in days in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, date-arithmetic

How would I get the age of a file in days in Ruby?

NOTE that I need a way to *accurately* get the age of a given file; this means that leap years need to be taken into account.

I need this for a program that removes files after they reach a certain age in days, such as files that are 20 days or older.

And by age, I mean the last access time of a given file, so if a file hasn't been accessed in the past 20 days or more, it gets deleted.

In Perl, I know that you can use [`date::calc`](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod) to calculate a date in terms of days since 1 AD, and I used to have a Common-Lisp program that used the Common-Lisp implementation of `date::calc`, but I don't have that anymore, so I've been looking for an alternative and Ruby seems to have the required capability.

Comment: You could subtract the POSIX Epoch time of the file from the current Epoch and then convert this to Days (it will be the age of the file in seconds.)

Comment: You might want to consider using the shell and the `find` command. It's built-into it to let you search for files older than a certain number of days. See its `atime` and `mtime` parameters when you do `man find`. While Ruby can do this, it's very straightforward with `find` and can easily result in a single-line command.

Comment: I have posted an answer that uses the method from my above comment, I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
path = '/path/to/file'    
(Time.now - File.stat(path).mtime).to_i / 86400.0
#=> 1.001232
```

Here is the implementation of my above comment, it returns a floating point number expressing the number of days passed.

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day, to explain the magic number!

Comment: what sense does it make to use `to_i` and then divide with a float?

Answer (score 6):

I know it is an old question, but I needed the same and came up with this solution that might be helpful for others.

As the difference is in days, there is not need to directly deal with seconds.

```
require 'date'
age_in_days = (Date.today - File.mtime(path).to_date).to_i
if age_in_days > 20
    # delete logs
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Rails, you can take advantage of ActiveSupport:

```
if File.mtime(path) < 20.days.ago
  # delete logs
end
```

If you aren't using Rails, Eduardo's solution above would be my pick.